# How to install Confluent Hub Client in Windows?

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

How [to install](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/confluent-hub/client.html#confluent-hub-client) Confluent Hub Client in Windows?

Comment: Install tutorial for Confluent with WSL can be found [here](https://nielsberglund.com/2018/07/10/install-confluent-platform-kafka-on-windows/). In my Opinion its the fastest way to setup and test Kafka, unless you already have Docker or VM prepared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can. The TARGZ package contains a Unix script, not a windows one.

That being said, you can still use WSL, Docker, Cygwin, a VM, etc. Then run Kafka Connect from there.

Comment: do you know how can install confluent-hub via docker?

Comment: It's already installed in Confluent images or see https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile.confluent-hub#L9